# How to add IP lookup commands to discord.js bot

Tags: command, discord, ip, discord.js, bots

Im trying to make and IP lookup bot that just shows as much information possible about the looked up ip, for example you would type something like:

`-ip [ip here]`

and the bot would return in an embed:

`**[IP/Header Here]**`

State:

City:

ISP:

etc

etc

etc

In the future I would like to add rockstar social club lookup as well (I assume its almost the exact same code.)

**note: im making this bot for fun and dont plan to use it maliciously**

I do know some knowledge about discord.js in general (as im developing a separate bot) but for something like this I have 0 prior knowledge so any other npm modules etc I need to install, please let me know :D

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for an API that'll give you info about the IP. Take a look at https://ipstack.com/ not recommending them in particular, just the first one I found. You can find a lot more with a simple google search.

Comment: thank you, would something like this work: 

`module.exports = {
    name: 'ip lookup',
    description: "gives info about a provided ip",
    execute(message, args) {

        const querystring = require('querystring');

if (command === 'lookup') {
  if (!args.length) {
    return message.channel.send('You need to supply a valid ip');
  }

 const query = querystring.stringify({ term: args.join(' ') });

  const { list } = await fetch(`http://api.ipstack.com/check
  ? access_key = MY KEY HERE ${query}`).then(response => response.json());
}}}`